# Pig: Filtering out the last tuple in a relation

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have below data in hdfs and I want to remove the last row.

### /user/cloudera/test/testfile.csv

```
Day,TimeCST,Conditions
1,12:53 AM,Clear
1,1:53 AM,Clear
1,2:53 AM,Clear
1,3:53 AM,Clear
1,4:53 AM,Clear
1,5:53 AM,Clear
1,6:53 AM,Clear
1,7:53 AM,Clear
1,8:53 AM,Clear
1,9:53 AM,Clear
1,10:53 AM,Clear
1,11:53 AM,Clear
1,12:53 PM,Clear
1,1:53 PM,Clear
1,2:53 PM,Clear
1,3:53 PM,Clear
1,4:53 PM,Clear
1,5:53 PM,Clear
```

First, I `load` the data, remove the header, and get the number of rows/tuples:

```
rawdata = LOAD 'hdfs:/user/cloudera/test/testfile.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (day:int, timecst:chararray, condition:chararray);
filtereddata = FILTER rawdata BY day > 0; --filters out header
rowcount = FOREACH (GROUP filtereddata ALL) GENERATE COUNT_STAR(filtereddata);
dump rowcount; --Prints (18)
```

Next, I `rank` the data and then try to use the generated row number to `filter` out the last row/tuple:

```
ranked = RANK filtereddata;
weatherdata = FILTER ranked BY $0 != rowcount.$0;
```

Above `filter` operation fails with the following error:

```
ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.
org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias weatherdata.....
```

However, if I hardcode the rowcount into my script as below, the job runs fine:

```
weatherdata = FILTER ranked BY $0 != 18;
```

I want to avoid hardcoding the rowcount. Did you detect where I might be going astray? Thanks.

**Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.5.0 (rexported)
compiled Nov 09 2015, 12:41:48**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of casting and naming the variable seems to do the trick. The following works:

```
rawdata = LOAD 'hdfs:/home/hduser/test/testfile.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (day:int, timecst:chararray, condition:chararray);
filtereddata = FILTER rawdata BY day > 0; --filters out header
rowcount = FOREACH (GROUP filtereddata ALL) GENERATE COUNT_STAR(filtereddata) AS mycount:long;
ranked = RANK filtereddata;
weatherdata = FILTER ranked BY $0 != rowcount.mycount;
dump weatherdata;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably have to cast it

```
weatherdata = FILTER ranked BY $0 != (int)rowcount.$0;
```

Comment: If casting would work, it should probably be `weatherdata = FILTER ranked BY $0 != (long)rowcount.$0;` because the row number field is long. Unfortunately, casting to `long` or `int` does not work. Same  ERROR 2017.